# elasticsearch - Date format requires exactly 3 decimals

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, iso8601

I'm having trouble with date parsing in elasticsearch 7.10.1.

Here's (a relevant part of) the mapping for the index:

```
"utcTime": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
}
```

[Date format reference.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

Some of the documents are accepted, for example documents with:

```
"utcTime": "2021-02-17T09:50:13.173Z"
"utcTime": "2021-02-17T09:51:44.158Z"
```

Note that in both cases, there are exactly 3 decimals to the seconds.

This, on the other hand, is rejected:

```
"utcTime": "2021-02-17T09:51:45.07Z"

illegal_argument_exception: failed to parse date field [2021-02-17T09:51:45.07Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSXX]
```

In this case, there are only two decimals. I'm using [Newtonsoft's JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do the serialization, with a format that should always include 3 decimals, but it doesn't seem to do so anyway. It'll include at most 3 decimals, though.

How can I tell elasticsearch to accept date formats with anywhere between 0 and 3 decimals for the seconds?

**EDIT**

I finally found the issue, which had nothing to do with the mapping, but rather with a pipeline processor `date_index_name`.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/test_reroute_pipeline
{
  "description" : "Route documents to another index",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "date_index_name": {
        "field": "utcTime",
        "date_rounding": "d",
        "index_name_prefix": "rerouted-"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Because the `date_format` parameter wasn't defined, it would remember the format of the first date received. If it was 2 decimals, it would require 2 every time. If it was 3, it would require three.

Specifying the date format solved the issue for good:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/test_reroute_pipeline
{
  "description" : "Route documents to another index",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "date_index_name": {
        "field": "utcTime",
        "date_rounding": "d",
        "index_name_prefix": "rerouted-",
        "date_formats": ["ISO8601"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? I just tested this on 7.10 and `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` accepts 1, 2 and 3 decimals

Comment: We're using 7.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried on a fresh new 7.10.1 cluster and it also accepted 1, 2, 3 decimals for the seconds part.

Looking at the error message you get

> illegal_argument_exception: failed to parse date field [2021-02-17T09:51:45.07Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSXX]

The format that seems to be set is `yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSXX` and it is different from `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ`

If you check the real mapping from your index, I'm pretty sure the `utcTime` field doesn't have `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` as the format.

Comment: It is the real mapping of my index :)

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get when running `GET your-index`, please?

Comment: Actually there’s more to the story: I’m using an ingest pipeline with a `date_index_name` processor to redirect documents to another index name. Somehow the index I redirect from seems to keep some kind of "memory" of the date format. I’ll edit the question when it’s all a little clearer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a mapping issue, but the datetime format in the pipeline processor. Thanks for your help, definitely steered me in the right direction!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!